# To-Do List: CheckBox activating every member of list

Tags: android-studio, flutter, listview, dart

I started creating a To-Do List App with Flutter.

And so far, I've added an AppBar, FloatingActionButton as adding button, List, TextField...

But I have a problem with the CheckBox IconButton. When its pressed it activates every member of the list instead only one.

Any solutions?

```
1  ListView.builder(
2     itemCount: todo.length,
3     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
4       return Card(
5         elevation: 5.0,
6         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
7           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
8         ),
9         margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
10         child: ListTile(
11          title: Text(
12            todo[index],
13          style: TextStyle(
14            color: (isPressed) ? Colors.grey[700] : Colors.black,
15            decoration: (isPressed) ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none
16          ),
17          ),
18          trailing: 
21              IconButton(
22                icon: Icon(
23                  Icons.check_box,
24                  color: (isPressed) ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.grey,
25                ),
26                onPressed: () {
27                  setState(() {
28                    isPressed = !isPressed;
29                  });
30                },
31              )
```

At line 15. I added when the button is pressed a.k.a activated the member of the list to be "done" by having a line through and its colors from black to go grey. But, when I activate the button that happens to all members of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, `isPressed` is used for all of your listview items while each item should has its own isPressed value. You can create a list of booleans and assign each one of them to a list item, something like this:

```
List<bool> _radioList=[false,...]; //its length should be equal to todo.length
```

And then in your list you can use:

```
color: (_radioList[index]) ? Colors.grey[700] : Colors.black,
decoration: (_radioList[index]) ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none
..
color: (_radioList[index]) ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.grey,
..
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
  _radioList[index] = !_radioList[index];
});
```

Comment: But todo.length is assigned by the user. I can't guess how many tasks will the user add

Comment: in that case when user adds a new task you just add a new value to _radioList. dont set a length for _radioList from start.